# AstroJS - Pipeline build successful on GH-Pages but keep getting 404

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, astrojs

I am trying to build a simple web page using Astro and deploy it on Github Pages to showcase something. The pipeline all green, but even after 1 day of waiting, I still get the 404 page unfound error. Here is the configs and related files that are used.

astro.config.mjs

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import node from "@astrojs/node";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  build:{
    site: 'https://my-personal-githubaccount.github.io/',
  },
  integrations: [react()],
  output: "server",
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone"
  }),
  plugins: [react({ jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react' })],
});
```

.github/workflows/deploy.yml

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout your repository using git
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.3
      - name: Install, build, and upload your site
        uses: withastro/action@v0.2.0
        with:
          node-version: 18
          package-manager: npm

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

Astro folder:

```
root
|- public/
   |- favicon.svg
|- src/
   |- a bunch of source codes files
|- package.json
|- tsconfig.json
|- astro.config.mjs
```

artifact.tar

```
|- ./
   |- client/
      |- _astro/
         |- some js, css, svg file here(no html file found)
      |- favicon.svg
   |- server/
      |- chunks/
         |- 2 .mjs files and one subfolder containing index.mjs
      |- entry.mjs
      |- renderers.mjs
```

Comment: If that requires the server to do more than just serve static assets, you can't do it with GitHub Pages.

Comment: GitHub Pages only supports static content (see docs like: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to deploy on github pages, you need to change

```js
output: "server"
```

to

```js
output: "static"
```

Astro reference

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#output

Github reference
"GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service..."

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages

Comment: Such a silly mistake from me, was tearing off my hair why either ```server``` or ```hybrid``` still won't do anything to make it available on gh-pages. Big thanks!